# Why is my React app with a large table slow and what can I do to speed it up?

Tags: reactjs

When my react app loads with 20-30 rows in a table it is fast and seems very responsive. When the number of rows gets up to 200-300 rows it lags a lot and I cannot figure out how to speed it up. It seems like all of the javascript takes a ton of time to load and nothing is efficient. Any suggestions?

I tried working with useMemo and making component React.memo components but this did not change the result.

```
const myComponent = () => {
      const [tableHeaders, setTableHeaders] = useState([]);
      const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);


      return(
             <div>
                  <table>
                         <thead>
                               <tr>
                               {tableHeaders.map((item, index) => <TableHeader item = {item} index = {index} />}
                               </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                        {tableData.map((item, index) => <TableRow item = {item} index = {index} tableHeaders = {tableHeaders} />}
                         </tbody>
                  </table>
             </div>
      )
}


const TableHeader = ({item, index}) => {
//table header logic here
return(
    <th>{item.Header}</th>
)

}

const TableRow = ({item, index, tableHeaders}) => (
     <tr>
       {tableHeaders.map((columnItem, index) => {
          //table row logic here
          return <td>{item[columnItem]}</td>
       })}
     </tr>

)


export default myComponent;
```

Comment: I don't think you're giving enough information to make any reasonable suggestion. Maybe if you share the component code... I would try to clean it up and simplify it first, in case the component is too large

Comment: Yes, need code to look at. In any case, for sure keep scrutinizing the React aspects, however you may also want to look at the table data format (ie maps vs arrays vs objects); there's differences in performance however usually it doesn't appear with this small of a data set. Are you using a 3rd-party table and you're feeding it correctly?

Comment: Just updated with generic layout of code to produce table. I am not using third party tables.